# how to align css content string

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

Hi guys I've created a toggle button from checkbox. I have a icon from awesome font as a css content. I've been trying almost everything but I'm not albe to align css content string in the middle of the circle.

Here is the css content part:

```
.onoffswitch-label:before {
    content: "\f000";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 4px 4px 0 0;
    background-color: #59B200;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 52px;
    border: 2px solid #59B200;
    border-radius: 38px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
```

Here is full example

http://jsfiddle.net/vzjyyob4/

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `text-align: center` to get the icon centered horizontally, then set `line-height` to a desired value to get it aligned vertically.

Here is the CSS for the label:

```
text-align: center;
line-height: 32px;
```

Here is an updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vzjyyob4/1/

---

And here is an inline **live demo**:

```css
.onoffswitch {
  position: relative;
  width: 94px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
  display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 38px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 38px;
  border: 2px solid #59B200;
  border-radius: 38px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
.onoffswitch-label:before {
  content: "\f000";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 4px 4px 0 0;
  background-color: #59B200;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 52px;
  border: 2px solid #59B200;
  border-radius: 38px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 32px;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label {
  background-color: #59B200;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label {
  border-color: #59B200;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label:before {
  border-color: #fff;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #59B200;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label:before {
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="onoffswitch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
  <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this CSS rule to align content:

```
.onoffswitch-label:before {
    text-align: center;
}
```

try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vzjyyob4/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use either `line-height` property:

```
.onoffswitch-label:before {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 32px;
}
```

Or flexbox:

```
.onoffswitch-label:before {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```